# How to set California DE4 allowances based on federal W4 allowances?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, state-income-tax, payroll-taxes

I need to set my federal and Calif payroll allowances to what they were 1/1/2015.

My federal was 29 allowances.  But I don't have record of Calif.

Can I deduce my Calif allowances based on federal 29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine what your exemptions were in the past check an old pay stub. Every company that I have worked for has included on the pay stub the number of federal and state exemptions.

Most people probably make them equal. But they don't have to be equal. Mine are not, because I have found that because my spouses income is variable the numbers needed to manage the refund size work best at different levels.